# Display drivers problem in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, drivers, display

I have windows 7 installed on my machine but display drivers are not being installed properly.

intel D865 GX270 Dell machine with built-in Display adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there after some looking around I found this [driver](http://justendeal.com/driver/855gm_vista_driver.zip)

It is the vista driver for the 855gm video chipset but it will most likely work for you.

The driver will have to be manually installed by going to the device manager under system, then right clicking on the bad video adapter and select update driver.  Make sure you select browse my computer, then point to the extracted folder.

with all luck you should be up and running.

Edit:

After some additional reading this driver should work for the 855/865/915 video chipsets as well.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Windows 7 x86 or x64? I would recommend using the device drivers supplied by Dell to begin with for troubleshooting this.

Alternatively, find out whether you have the 865G or 865GV and select the graphics driver from :
http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/sb/CS-009241.htm

You may also find the Intel Driver Detect tool useful for downloading the correct driver:
http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/detect.htm

To find your chipset you may need to use a tool like CPU-Z. Also it may help to open up Device Manager and see which components are missing drivers.

Comment: If its a GX270, that makes it a socket-478 Pentium 4.  Should be running 32-bit.

Comment: It appears this device is legacy, but Intel has XPDM drivers that will work with Windows 7. Note that no support is provided. http://www.intel.com/support/graphics/sb/CS-030907.htm

Answer (score 0):

According to the Dell support site, the [drivers page](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/driverslist.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=gen&ServiceTag=&SystemID=PLX_PNT_CEL_GX270&os=WW1&osl=en&catid=&impid) for the GX270 shows XP as its last supported Windows operating system.

You're certainly going to have quite a few problems with installing Windows 7 on this computer. You're really lucky to have gotten along so far. I would really advice going back to XP, and maybe using Windows 7 in a virtual machine.

If you really insist on Windows 7, there's no point in consulting the online Dell Support. You would need to find out which are your components and download drivers from the manufacturer's site (if available). Regard Drive Manager, where all yellow-marked entries signal a missing driver. You must install all the drivers in order to have a fully-functioning computer.

Answer (score 0):

simple answer, the Intel 82865G does not work with Windows Vista/7.

but all is not lost, the Dell Optiplex G270 got an AGP slot, get a cheap AGP video card (e.g. some old Radeon X series or a Geforce FX5200) and it will run Windows 7.

i have the same machine here and it works like a charm with a Radeon x600.

Comment: i'd recommend a GeForce 6200 over the 5200; both are still available in AGP configurations for nearly the same price at NewEgg, and the 6200 is a vastly more capable chip.

Comment: basically anything AGP will do, even a TNT2 with 32 MB RAM is running circles around the Intel 865 and still works in Windows 7 :)

Comment: ha.  i wouldn't go that far.  i've still got a TNT2 in what's nominally a headless system... i'm hoping to upgrade it to a GeForce 4 soon (hahahahahahahaha)

Comment: i wouldn't invest any money in the old optiplex, the PC2700 memory is a big bottleneck and the machine is much better off with XP anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Taspeotis,

Prior to migrating to Windows 7 from Windows XP did you run the Windows 7 Upgrade Advisor?
To determine if your current computer configuration will be compatible with Windows 7 please go to the following link: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windows-7/get/upgrade-advisor.aspx

Another resource to verify compatibility is available at the Microsoft Windows 7 Compatibility Center located at the following link: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/compatibility/windows-7/en-us/default.aspx

You may want to ultimately try to install these drivers through compatibility mode.

Jessica
Microsoft Windows Client Team

Comment: I'm not having this problem, Mr-Right is